# Divide a 3d numpy array into 2 groups python

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

i have a 3d array in this form (12457,8,6) i wand to divide it into 2 equal numpy arrays like (12457,3,8)
In fact that the first one containt the first 3 bands and the second one contains the remaind bands: In other words I want my array1 contains the bands 1,2,3 and my array2 contains the bands 4,5,6

I tried with that but it doesnt work

```
array1=data[:,:,3]
array1.shape
(12457,8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.split` -

```
X = np.random.random((1200,6,8))
print(X.shape)

X1, X2 = np.split(X, 2, axis=1) #Array, num of splits, axis for splitting
print(X1.shape, X2.shape)
```

```
(1200, 6, 8)
(1200, 3, 8) (1200, 3, 8)
```

Comment: Read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

Answer (score 0):

[split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) or [array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) should be able to help you out.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
newarr = np.split(arr, 2)
print(newarr)
```

Prints:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]]), array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])]
```

Comment: Hi UncleCid, welcome to SO. This answer is exactly the same as one already answered. If you do see an answer please refrain from posting the same (in this case you posted the exact solution almost 5 minutes after it was already answered). Instead, just comment on the previous answer to add more value to it.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I was busy writing the solution while that one was being posted.  I didn't think to refresh the page to see if any solutions had appeared.  I suppose I should delete it then?

Comment: No thats all right, these things happen. Its just a respected practice here, thats all.