# Splitting numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, `arr`,  of `shape(1000, 400, 56)`

For context, `400` represents the time bins, `56` represents a motion vector. `1000` is the nr of samples

For each sample, I want to split the array (the `400, 56` part) in a grid like fashion. For example I want `4, 200, 28`. Where the `28` part for each sample is from splitting the motion vector in half and placing it in one of the `4` samples separately (note in this case the time would have been split in half also).

The problem with doing `reshape(4, 200, 28)` is that it splits the `56` into x2 `28` and places them right after the other consecutively (in the same sample array) which is undesired. I want the first half of the `56` to be in one sample array and the second half to be in another sample array such that the `x56` motion vector is split in half.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Permute first and rearrange to be 1000, 56,400 then reshape (1000, 4 , 28,200) then rearrange again (1000, 4, 200, 28) is that what you want?

Comment: As far as i understand this post should solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467809/divide-a-3d-numpy-array-into-2-groups-python

Comment: @amirhm unfortunately not, it seems to create arrays that are all over the place (I confirmed with plotting also)

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a minimal reproducible example. With smaller size, obviously. So an example `arr` and an example output after splitting.

Comment: A first step is reshape the (1000, 400, 56) to (1000,2,200,2,28).  Then use `transpose` or `swapaxes` to get a (1000,2,2,200,28).  Then a final reshape.